# Unknown log trace in Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

One of our customers is asking us about this logs:

```
- 23.1.148.45 - - 0.000 [22/Jan/2015:13:24:32 +0100] GET /mancenter-2.6.9/getTask.do?member=1.5.24.32:5556&cluster=BACK HTTP/1.1 200 4 - Java/1.7.0_65
- 23.1.148.45 - - 0.000 [22/Jan/2015:13:24:32 +0100] GET /mancenter-2.6.9/getTask.do?member=1.5.24.32:5560&cluster=BACK HTTP/1.1 200 4 - Java/1.7.0_65
```

I know that is mostly spam and in newer versions it dissapears, but we want to know what is it and how can we configure to silent it. Someone could answer us?

Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: only difference is `member=1.5.24.32:5556` vs `member=1.5.24.32:5560` right?

Comment: @Coffee yes, is the only difference.

Answer (score 1):

It is a http request to the mancenter --> ManagementCenter. It is a Hazelcast monitoring solution that is part of the enterprise package.

Did you configure the mancenter in your hazelcast.xml?

Comment: Yes, they add the following line: `<management-center enabled="true">http://host.customer:port/mancenter</management-center>`.

Comment: It's normal to see those access logs when mancenter is configured. Each Hazelcast node sends http request to mancenter periodically to check for waiting tasks. (Like Man. center "Console" or "Script" tab tasks, or "Browse Map" and "Map Config" tasks)

Comment: @emrahkocaman thanks for the info. Is there any posible solution to avoid it?. It overflows our log...

Comment: These look like http access logs so they are not logged by Hazelcast. IMHO you need to check your web server's (where mancenter is deployed) logging settings.